# Best way to retrieve top tokens in TF-IDF models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

How may one go about getting an overview of most important tokens from a SciKit-learn pipeline with the following components:

```
multinb = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
           ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
           ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
          ])

multinb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Looking for a simple snippet that visualizes/plots the top-weighted tokens overall X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about extracting the `coef_` of `MultinomialNB`:

```
import pandas as pd


multinb = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
           ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
           ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
          ])

multinb.fit(X_train, y_train)

token_imp = pd.DataFrame(
    data=multinb['clf'].coef_[0],
    index=multinb['vect'].get_feature_names(),
    columns=['coefficient']
).sort_values(by='coefficient', ascending=False)

print(token_imp)
```

This will give you something like feature importances in descending order. Since `token_imp` is a dataframe, you can also just view the *n* most important features by using `token_imp.head(n)` and visualize them with `token_imp.plot.bar()`

Comment: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1234), indices imply (1234, 1)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to index `coef_` as it returns an array of shape (n_classes, n_features). Updated the answer.

Comment: ).sort_values(by="coefficient",ascending=False)